# Dragonslaying story involving a dwarf and a warriormaid

Tags: story-identification

It's a fantasy story, set in a world with kingdoms and dragons. The basic plot is that a dwarf and a human princess (called a warriormaid, I think) go off to slay a dragon, and the princess dies.

I have been drawing a blank for years trying to remember the title -
anyone have any idea what it might be?

Comment: Was “warriormaid” one word or two?

Comment: Also, can you recall anything else? For example, how long was “years ago”?

Comment: Does the princess die by accident, or of natural causes, or is she killed by the dwarf, or the dragon, or someone else? What happens to the dragon, does it get slain? Why do the dwarf and the princess want to slay the dragon?

Comment: I guess Dragondoom is the fifth book set in that world...the first is called the Iron tower and it sounds familiar, so I might have read it, or just had it in my hand at some point in a bookstore....oh and adamant, I must have read it in the mid 90's, but Dragondoom is definitely it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be "Dragondoom" by Dennis L. McKiernan.

http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/554771.Dragondoom

> Against this unholy alliance, two sworn enemies set forth to find a legendary long-lost weapon: a warhammer of incalculable power that may be the only hope of victory. But neither the Warrior Maiden Elyn nor the Dwarf Thork is prepared for the dangers awaiting them on this quest.

Her father was King Aranor, which makes her a princess. She was also killed by the dragon.

Comment: That looks like it is probably it.

Comment: THATS IT...DRAGONDOOM!!!!  I remember the dragons name "sleeth"  THANK YOU SO MUCH, its been nagging me for years now lol

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept this as the correct answer by clicking the tick above.